# ERROR: could not open file "C:\Users\kelly\Downloads\orders_data.csv" for reading: No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-copy

It shows this when I try to import a csv file to my postgresql

I did this but still shows similar error

```
COPY public."orders_data" from 'C:\Users\kelly\Downloads\orders_data.csv' DELIMITERS ',' csv Header;
```

I have created my table already, I just want to import the csv files into the table but I keep getting error message

Comment: do you have the file open in another program while copying? if you have this file open in excel and you try to 'copy' it will fail. make a copy of the file to c:\orders data.csv and try again

Comment: No, only my postgresql terminal is opened.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, show us a print scren of the folder or a "dir" output in cmd from the "downloads" folder showing the **name and extension** of the csv as well as the path to the directory. Sidenote, the separator keyword is DELIMITE**R**, not DELIMITE**RS**.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name do you mean something like this "COPY  c:\orders data.csv from 'C:\Users\kelly\Downloads\orders_data.csv' DELIMITERS ',' csv Header";

Comment: @TheNomad Thank you for the side not, I have corrected the 'Delimiter'

Comment: Don't forget to update the code (with DELIMITE**R**) in the question as well. Also show us the directory and file inside the dir, please!

Comment: If that's a local database cluster, running on the same system as your client, this should work. Otherwise, use psql [`\copy`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY) instead, so that the path points at a file visible to your local client, not the remote server - [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) looks at the db server filesystem. @TheNomad Both `DELIMITER` and `DELIMITERS` with an `S` [are supported](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html#id-1.9.3.55.11).

Comment: @TheNomad Thank you for the side note, I have corrected the 'Delimiter' and the file location. it has worked now. Thank you very much

Comment: the file name ought to be "orders_data-orders_data" but I wrote o"rders_ data". And also the spelling of the "Delimiter". So the issue has been resolved thanks for the help